Directory index by google crawler
After the latest update of Google, I found a lot of urls in my search console related to Directory pages. I found a 6k URL for my /wp-content/uploads and /wp-content/plugins.
these are destroying my crawl budget and it's dangerous for my website!
if I block this directory in .htaccess, I prevent the image index?
how should I fix it?
is there anybody with the same experience?
I've searched and found I should block this path in .htaccess file

@UmeshSingh I'm interested to understand why your promoted this to the main site; how is this about programming or software develop,ent? There's not even a programming language tagged, and SEO and Wordpress have nothing to with with either subject either.
